# Python convert object of class to int

Tags: python, object, hash

I'm new in Python. And I have a task to make a double hash table for arrray and for doubly linked list. I have a code which work with array and code with doubly linked list. But I don't know how convert my object with `linked_list` to `int`. I know how convert it on Java just using class Integer but in Python I don't know. I tried to make a function `def int(self)` and return `self.data` but it doesn't work. I tried to find how make template or somethig like this but didn't find anything. Please help me.

This is a code:

```
from random import randint
class doubleHashTable:
    # initialize hash Table
    def __init__(self):
        self.size = int(input("Enter the Size of the hash table : "))
        self.num = 5
        # initialize table with all elements 0
        self.table = list(0 for i in range(self.size))
        self.elementCount = 0
        self.comparisons = 0

    # method that checks if the hash table is full or not
    def isFull(self):
        if self.elementCount == self.size:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    # method that returns position for a given element
    # replace with your own hash function
    def h1(self, element):
        return element % self.size

    # method that returns position for a given element
    def h2(self, element):
        return element % self.num

    # method to resolve collision by quadratic probing method
    def doubleHashing(self, element, position):
        posFound = False
        # limit variable is used to restrict the function from going into infinite loop
        # limit is useful when the table is 80% full
        limit = 50
        i = 2
        # start a loop to find the position
        while i <= limit:
            # calculate new position by quadratic probing
            newPosition = (i * self.h1(element) + self.h2(element)) % self.size
            # if newPosition is empty then break out of loop and return new Position
            if self.table[newPosition] == 0:
                posFound = True
                break
            else:
                # as the position is not empty increase i
                i += 1
        return posFound, newPosition

    # method that inserts element inside the hash table
    def insert(self, element):
        # checking if the table is full
        if self.isFull():
            print("Hash Table Full")
            return False

        posFound = False

        position = self.h1(element)

        # checking if the position is empty
        if self.table[position] == 0:
            # empty position found , store the element and print the message
            self.table[position] = element
            print("Element " + str(element) + " at position " + str(position))
            isStored = True
            self.elementCount += 1

        # collision occured hence we do linear probing
        else:
            while not posFound:
                print("Collision has occured for element " + str(element) + " at position " + str(
                    position) + " finding new Position.")
                posFound, position = self.doubleHashing(element, position)
                if posFound:
                    self.table[position] = element
                    self.elementCount += 1

        return posFound

    # method that searches for an element in the table
    # returns position of element if found
    # else returns False
    def search(self, element):
        found = False
        position = self.h1(element)
        self.comparisons += 1

        if (self.table[position] == element):
            return position

        # if element is not found at position returned hash function
        # then we search element using double hashing
        else:
            limit = 50
            i = 2
            newPosition = position
            # start a loop to find the position
            while i <= limit:
                # calculate new position by double Hashing
                position = (i * self.h1(element) + self.h2(element)) % self.size
                self.comparisons += 1
                # if element at newPosition is equal to the required element

                if self.table[position] == element:

                    found = True
                    break

                elif self.table[position] == 0:
                    found = False
                    break

                else:
                    # as the position is not empty increase i
                    i += 1
            if found:
                return position
            else:
                print("Element not Found")
                return found

                # method to remove an element from the table

    def remove(self, element):
        position = self.search(element)
        if position is not False:
            self.table[position] = 0
            print("Element " + str(element) + " is Deleted")
            self.elementCount -= 1
        else:
            print("Element is not present in the Hash Table")
        return

    # method to display the hash table
    def display(self):
        print("\n")
        for i in range(self.size):
            print(str(i) + " = " + str(self.table[i]))
        print("The number of element is the Table are : " + str(self.elementCount))

"""DOUBLY-LINKED LIST"""
class Node():
    def __init__(self, next_node=None, previous_node=None, data=None):
        self.next_node = next_node
        self.previous_node = previous_node
        self.data = data

class LinkedList():
    def __init__(self, node):
        assert isinstance(node, Node)
        self.first_node = node
        self.last_node = node

    def push(self, node):
        '''Pushes the node <node> at the "front" of the ll
        '''
        node.next_node = self.first_node
        node.previous_node = None
        self.first_node.previous_node = node
        self.first_node = node

    def pop(self):
        '''Pops the last node out of the list'''
        old_last_node = self.last_node
        to_be_last = self.last_node.previous_node
        to_be_last.next_node = None
        old_last_node.previous_node = None

        # Set the last node to the "to_be_last"
        self.previous_node = to_be_last

        return old_last_node

    def removing(self, node):
        '''Removes and returns node, and connects the previous and next
        '''
        next_node = node.next_node
        previous_node = node.previous_node

        previous_node.next_node = next_node
        next_node.previous_node = previous_node

        # Make it "free"
        node.next_node = node.previous_node = None

        return node

    # def int(self):
    #     return self.data

    def __str__(self):
        next_node = self.first_node
        s = ""
        while next_node:
            s += "--({:2d})--\n".format(next_node.data)
            next_node = next_node.next_node
        return s
        return


# main function

"""LISTS1"""
print("\nLISTS\n")
node1 = Node(data=1)
linked_list = LinkedList(node1)
for i in range(100):
    if i == 5:
        node1 = Node(data=5)
        linked_list.push(node1)
    else:
        linked_list.push(Node(data=i))
print (linked_list)

print ("popping")
liast = linked_list.pop().data
#print(type(liast))
print(liast)
print (linked_list)
lalalal = linked_list
print(type(lalalal))
#print (linked_list.pop().data)

table_list1 = doubleHashTable()
for i in range (100):
    table_list1.insert(lalalal)

# displaying the Table
table_list1.display()
print()

# printing position of elements
print("The position of element 31 is : " + str(table_list1.search(31)))
print("The position of element 28 is : " + str(table_list1.search(28)))
print("The position of element 90 is : " + str(table_list1.search(90)))
print("The position of element 77 is : " + str(table_list1.search(77)))
print("The position of element 1 is : " + str(table_list1.search(1)))
print("\nTotal number of comaprisons done for searching = " + str(table_list1.comparisons))
print()

table_list1.remove(90)
table_list1.remove(12)

table_list1.display()


# storing elements in table
# table1.insert(12)
# table1.insert(26)
# table1.insert(31)
# table1.insert(17)
# table1.insert(90)
# table1.insert(28)
# table1.insert(88)
# table1.insert(40)
# table1.insert(77)  # element that causes collision at position 0
```

This is error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "python", line 225, in <module>
File "python", line 57, in insert
File "python", line 22, in h1
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'LinkedList' and 'int'
```

Comment: Nevermind. Just scrolled down.

Comment: You might attract more help by focusing on the "minimal" part of a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Could you explain us why you want to cast a linked_list into an integer? Can't you just get the integer attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

short version use `hash(element)` on `h1()` and other places (`h2()`) at your code that use the hash of the object to determine is position in the hash table

you are inserting a linked_list `lalalal`

```
lalalal = linked_list
table_list1.insert(lalalal)
```

to calculate it's position you are using this method

```
def h1(self, element):
        return element % self.size
```

you are trying to get mod from linked_list object and int, as the error state

you need to convert your linked list to some representation of number using some logic (uniform hash function is the best)

try to use smth like `to_hash()` on linked_list that will return `int` so

```
def h1(self, element):
        return element.to_hash() % self.size
```

you can also override `__hash__` and use `hash(element)`

Those few changes will make your code **run**

```
def h1(self, element):
    return hash(element) % self.size

def h2(self, element):
    return hash(element) % self.num
```

and in the `LinkedList` class add

```
def __hash__(self):
    return randint(1, 1000)
```

Note: this hash function is for draft purpose only, in case your has map will be bigger than 1000 or what ever fixed value you choose, the elements won't be uniformly distributed over the map, this could effect the map performance...

Comment: this `def __hash__(self):` must be in class `doubleHashTable`?

Comment: @Lado, no it's need to be in linked_list class

Comment: sorry again. I used this `def __hash__(self, element):` and then return `return hash(element)`. Then use it in class `doubleHashTable` like `hash(element) % self.size` in `def h1(self, element)` but I have this error `TypeError: __hash__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'element'`. I must define this element in LinkedList class?

Comment: @Lado, don't be, I edited the answer and added the changes need to be made in order for your code to run...